# Unexpected output: vector of vector (power set)

Tags: c++, vector, push-back, powerset

I am trying to write the solution to one of the problems of CTCI - Write a method to return all subsets of a set. However, I'm not getting an expected output. There seems to be a silly error but I'm unable to spot it. Below is the code:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> power_set( const std::vector<T>& input ) {
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> output;
    for ( const auto& element : input ) {
        power_set_helper( element, output );
    }
    return output;
}

template <typename T>
void power_set_helper( const T& element, std::vector<std::vector<T>>& output ) {
    for ( auto set_element : output ) {
        set_element.push_back( element );
        output.push_back( set_element );
    }
    output.emplace_back( std::initializer_list<T>{element} );
}
```

TEST CASE:

```
std::vector<int> input                       = {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<std::vector<int>> expected_ouput = {{1}, {1, 2}, {2}, {1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}, {3}};
```

But the output I get is :
    { { 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2 }, { 1, 3 }, { 1, 2, 3 }, { 3 }, { 3 } }

Can you please help in spotting the error and share the reason for it?

Comment: You really don't have the empty set `{}` in your expected output?

Comment: I was not intending to have an empty set for this solution. The issue was with the copy of output variable

Answer (score 1):

```
for ( auto set_element : output ) {
    // ...
    output.push_back( set_element );
```

Here you modify vector on which you iterate, leading to UB

Possible solution is to make a copy

```
for ( auto set_element : std::vector<std::vector<T>>(output) ) {
    // ...
    output.push_back( set_element );
```

Comment: Thanks. this works. Will implement by creating a copy of a vector rather than the whole output.